# Return a value from a stored procedure and use it to call a second stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have these 3 stored procedures where the first one calls the other two.

All I want to do is to return the `@ChildID` from the second stored procedure, and use that value when I call the third one. The third one never gets the `@ChildID` value.

Is it not possible to return a value from one stored procedure and back to the caller stored procedure ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [stg].[SP_DoSomeHeavyStuff]
    @parentId int 
AS
    DECLARE @ChildId INT, 
            @StartDateTime datetime2(7) = GETDATE(),
            @Table nvarchar(255) = 'SalesOrderHeader'

    EXEC stg.Start @StartDateTime, @Table, @ChildId

    -- Code that do some heavy stuff goes here

    EXEC stg.EndLog @ChildId
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [stg].[Start] 
    @ParentId int, 
    @StartTime datetime2(7), 
    @Table Nvarchar(255), 
    @ChildID int 
AS
    INSERT INTO stg.[Log](ParentId, StartTime, [Table]) 
    VALUES (@ParentId, @StartTime, @Table) 

    SELECT @ChildID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    RETURN @ChildID
```

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [stg].[EndLog] 
    @ChildId int 
AS
    UPDATE stg.[Log]
    SET EndTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE ChildID = @ChildId
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

In a Stored Procedures RETURN is inteded for a status code indicating success or failure to old TSQL code written before the introduction of TRY/CATCH error handling.

You should [return data using an output parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Transact-SQL%20procedures%20can%20use%20the%20cursor%20data%20type,specified%20for%20that%20parameter%20in%20the%20procedure%20definition.). eg

```
Create procedure [stg].[Start] @ParentId int, @StartTime datetime2(7), @Table Nvarchar(255), @ChildID int output
as
begin
    INSERT INTO stg.[Log](ParentId, StartTime, [Table]) 
    VALUES (@ParentId, @StartTime, @Table) 

    set @ChildID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end
```

then

```
 exec stg.Start @StartDateTime, @Table, @ChildId output
```